# why new Comparable[(currentMaxIndex + 2) * 11 / 10] while construct a heap from given array?

Tags: java, binary-heap

THe book *Data structure and algorithm analysis in Java* gives the code of BinaryHeap's constructor

```
public BinaryHeap(AnyType[] items){
    currentMaxIndex = items.length;
    this.items = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[(currentMaxIndex + 2) * 11 / 10];
    int i = 1;
    for(AnyType item : items){
        this.items[i++] = item;
    }
    buildHead();
}
```

Why is the space of Comparable[] (currentMaxIndex + 2) * 11 / 10? What's the meaning of doing this?

Comment: By the way. This is classical bug in integer overflow. You can't create this BinaryHeap over items when items.length > ~200 millions. Correct code will be some thing like `new Comparable[currentMaxIndex + 2 + currentMaxIndex/10]`

Comment: It's seems that it is just allocating some additional space for future growth.